# PyTube error: pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*

Tags: python, regex, tkinter, pytube

**This is my code of downloading YouTube video using python tkinter which is working fine but after inserting in def ytVidDownloader(), its not working (inserted in def because it was module of my project)**

***(Shorten both programs for better understanding)***

**Main Dashboard File is**

```
from tkinter import *
import moduleYVD
window= Tk()
window.geometry("750x600")
Button(window, text = "YouTube Video Downloader", command = moduleYVD.ytVidDownloader).pack(pady=18)
window.mainloop()
```

**ModuleYVD is :**

```
from tkinter import *
from pytube import YouTube

def ytVidDownloader():
   root = Tk()
   root.geometry('500x300')
   link = StringVar()
   link_enter = Entry(root, width = 70,textvariable = link).place(x = 32, y = 130)
   def Downloader():                #function to download video
      url =YouTube(str(link.get()))
      video = url.streams.first()
      video.download()
      Label(root, text = 'DOWNLOADED', font = 'arial 15').place(x= 180 , y = 210)

   Button(root,text = 'DOWNLOAD', font = 'arial 15 bold' , padx = 2, command = Downloader).place(x=80 ,y = 190)
   root.mainloop()
```

**And the error I am getting is :**

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Project ToolKit\moduleYVD.py", line 34, in Downloader
    #function to download video
  File "C:\Users\kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.video_id = extract.video_id(url)
  File "C:\Users\kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 133, in video_id
    return regex_search(r"(?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*", url, group=1)
  File "C:\Users\kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\helpers.py", line 129, in regex_search
    raise RegexMatchError(caller="regex_search", pattern=pattern)
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*
```

**How can I solve this error ?**

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question. You have to help us to help you.

Comment: The regex is failing to match a string, but without the string, no-one can say why it's failing, nor how to correct.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer of my own question.
Just import both pytube and YouTube from pytube libraries separately:

```
import pytube
from pytube import YouTube
```